# How can apache access a file in a directory which has no execute permission?

Tags: permissions, apache2.4

I am trying to open an html file which is inside a directory that has no execute permission for apache group. Therefore when I try to access the file from apache it displays the error "You don't have permission to access / on the server.". Is there any way I can open the file without changing the permissions of the directory but by editing the access control directives in apache2.conf?

Comment: I want to do it by editing the apache.conf this time which was not suggested in any of the answers of the related post.

Comment: What you're asking is impossible. You can't configure Apache to circumvent the discretionary access control of the Linux kernel. That would defeat the purpose of DAC.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is also subject to the permissions set on any file it accesses. There's nothing you can set it in the Apache configuration that will give it more access than filesystem permissions allow.

Comment: But since the html file is read only and read permission is the only permission that the server needs to open it I thought it could be a way to access the file from server even without having execute permission on the directory that contains the file. I was thinking in analogy with the fact that when a directory has no execute permission you can not cd on it however you can open files inside it if you know their paths.

Comment: @ElioNushi I'm not sure where you got that fact, but that's not true.

Comment: @enu It's read permission that you must be thinking of. For example (I've omitted a number of things so you just see the relevant parts): *d--x--x--x  temp*; if I were to do *ls -l temp* I would get: *ls: cannot open directory 'temp': Permission denied*. However I know for a fact there is a file called 'temp' and I have the following permissions on it: *-rw-rw-r--  temp/test* which ls would show (well it'd show a bit more information but the point is I have +x on the directory but do not have +r on the directory; I do however have access to the file as long as I know the absolute path).

Comment: Oh and yes I can indeed write to that file. Now if I were to *chmod -w* on it it'd show no write access (read-only) but I can force a write in e.g. *vi* by *:w!* Of course this is in a default set up and test to demonstrate it to you. But why you would want to do this with Apache is beyond me...